# How to keep my PowerPC Macbook Pro running OSX 10.5.8 Leopard secure?

Tags: macbook-pro, security, leopard, web-browser, powerpc

I have a pretty fast and good Macbook Pro with PowerPC chips inside. I cannot upgrade to newer operating systems anymore, and do not receive any upgrades anymore. Therefore, I an concerned about how secure the machine still is.

Are there any ways to keep it secure?

Comment: There is no MacBook Pro with a PowerPC inside. All the MacBook and MacBook Pro range use Intel chips. Please clarify your question.

Comment: ah. that is strange. I have actually shipped the MBP to a friend of mine. I was certain it had PowerPC, because there was no possibility of upgrading the OS. I will ask him to check it, and will provide an answer here.

Comment: It is possible the Mac is a PowerBook G4, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerBook_G4

Answer (score 1):

## Apple's Security Guide

Apple released a [Security Configuration Guide for Mac OS X 10.5](https://ssl.apple.com/support/security/guides/docs/Leopard_Security_Config_2nd_Ed.pdf), aka Leopard:

> The [Security Configuration Guides](https://ssl.apple.com/support/security/guides/) provide an overview of features in
>   Mac OS X that can be used to enhance security, known as hardening your
>   computer.
>
> The guides are designed to give instructions and recommendations for
>   securing Mac OS X and for maintaining a secure computer.

### NSA Configuration Guide

Another source of advice for securing your Mac is from the NSA. The NSA also [provide security configuration guides](http://www.nsa.gov/ia/mitigation_guidance/security_configuration_guides/operating_systems.shtml) for hardening your Mac.

The [NSA guide for Mac OS X 10.5](http://www.nsa.gov/ia/_files/factsheets/macosx_hardening_tips.pdf) is available as a PDF.

Advice beyond these guides depends on how you use your Mac. If it is connected to the Internet and providing services such as file sharing, screen sharing, or remote login then you may wish to investigate updating some open source packages.